# Не получается реализовать авторизацию в спринг секьюрити

Tags: java, авторизация, spring-security

Не авторизуется пользователь при вводе верных логина (в моем случае почта) и пароля. Пытался проверить в чем ошибка через точку остановы, но в `loadUserByUsername` даже не заходит.
Регистрация при этом работает исправно. Из за того что пытался не использовать `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, получилось, так что не очень много инфы смог найти. Самому  разобраться не хватает опыта.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/main").setViewName("main");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("main");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/registration").setViewName("registration");
    }
}
```

...

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests)->requests
                        .requestMatchers("/login","/static/**","/registration").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form)->form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout)->logout.permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

...

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
@Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }
    public User findUserById(Long userId){
        Optional<User> userFromDb = userRepository.findById(userId);
        return userFromDb.orElse(new User());
    }
    public List<User> allUser(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    public boolean saveUser(User user){
        User userFromDb = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getUsername());
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        String email = user.getEmail();
        if(userRole == null){
            userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
            if(userRole == null)    {
                Role role = new Role("ROLE_USER");
            roleRepository.save(role);
            }
        }
        if(userFromDb != null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setRole(userRole);
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean deleteUser(Long userId){
        if(userRepository.findById(userId).isPresent()){
            userRepository.deleteById(userId);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public List<User> usergtList(List idMin){
        return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id > :paramId", User.class)
                .setParameter("paramId", idMin).getResultList();
    }
}
```

...

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Transient
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<User> users;
    public Role(){

    }
    public Role(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getName();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```